# compare an array with a object and return an array of objects by deleting the object if object already exists in that array

Tags: javascript

```
const allProducts=[
    { id:1, productName:'Apple',price:100,quantity:1}
    { id:2, productName:'Cherry',price:70,quantity:1}
    { id:3, productName:'Orange',price:60,quantity:1}
    { id:4, productName:'Grapes',price:69,quantity:1}
]

let cart =[ ]
```

object is `{ id:4, productName:'Grapes',price:69,quantity:1}`

```
const addToCart = (object) =>
{
    let a = cart.filter(items=>{
}
```

result should be this

```
[
    { id:4, productName:'Grapes',price:69,quantity:1}
]
```

Comment: Your result is identical to your starting array?

Comment: if cart is empty push that object in the cart (avoid duplicate objects) and if cart is not empty compare whether it exist ...if so dont push else push it in the cart

Comment: So you want an array with unique objects ? Your question sets different expectations than your comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply check if the object exits in the array, and if not push it into the array:

```
if (!cart.includes(object)){
    cart.push(object);
}
```

Comment: Provided the object is actually the same object, and not just something that looks the same.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will work in your case, but you could use [Set()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/Set) that can contain either primitive values or references. Here I'm using the reference to the allProducts array to add items to the Set. In a Set all items must be unique.

```js
const allProducts = [
  { id:1, productName:'Apple',price:100,quantity:1},
  { id:2, productName:'Cherry',price:70,quantity:1},
  { id:3, productName:'Orange',price:60,quantity:1},
  { id:4, productName:'Grapes',price:69,quantity:1}
];

let cart = new Set();

cart.add(allProducts[0]);
cart.add(allProducts[2]);
console.log(cart.size);

cart.add(allProducts[0]);
console.log(cart.size);

console.log([...cart]);
```